# Use of backticks (``) in JS results in empty lines

Tags: javascript, backticks

I have used the backticks syntax in order to generate some Java code with Javascript:

```
${body ? `con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(${JSON.stringify(body)});
wr.flush();
wr.close();` : ``}

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

However, when body is null, the generated code contains 3-4 empty lines and then 
the "int responseCode .." line.
I have tried extracting the part where body is true into a separate constant or moving the `` as first in the statement and none of them works. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have `${` before `body`?

Comment: The `${....}` syntax works only inside backticks, so its curious why the first line has this syntax outside of backticks.  More curiously, you aren't getting a "Syntax error: Unexpected token {" error?

Comment: Sorry. It's within backticks, it's something like:
``.....
${body ? `con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(${JSON.stringify(body)});
wr.flush();
wr.close();` : ``}

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
.....``

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you check correctly the body's var, e.g:

```
typeof body == "undefined" ? `con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(${JSON.stringify(body)});
wr.flush();
wr.close();` : ``
```

Will return the string below:

```
"con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(${JSON.stringify(body)});
wr.flush();
wr.close();"
```

Not use just `body ? "string" : ""`, do some operation with the body's var. (e.g `body == ""` or `typeof body == "undefined"`)

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with your js?